# Connecting to Google Analytics 4 API - com.google.auth.oauth2.GdchCredentials does not exist

Tags: java, maven, google-analytics, classnotfoundexception

I've been trying for several days to connect to my GA4 service account via the GA4 API to pull statistics.

I'm following the official example at

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries

I'm trying to NOT use the environment variable to find the client secrets json info, but rather referencing the file in /src/main/resources in NetBeans (client_secrets.json) directly in code, so came up with this:

```
GoogleCredentials gc =  ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"))
                    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL));            
            
BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings = BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(gc)).build();
            
BetaAnalyticsDataClient betaAnalyticsDataClient = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings);
```

I want to use this just above the line

```
try (BetaAnalyticsDataClient analyticsData = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create()) {
```

line in the official Google example linked to above, to get a BetaAnalyticsDataClient instance with my client_secrets.json file's credentials by directly referencing it.

E.g. therefore pulling the credential file by referencing its location and reading it as a ResourceAsStream, not from the implied environment variable as the official example does.

My code compiles and runs but on this line of the above code

```
BetaAnalyticsDataClient betaAnalyticsDataClient = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings);
```

I get a runtime exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.auth.oauth2.GdchCredentials
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.stub.GrpcBetaAnalyticsDataStub.create(GrpcBetaAnalyticsDataStub.java:149) ~[google-analytics-data-0.32.0.jar:0.32.0]
    at com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.stub.BetaAnalyticsDataStubSettings.createStub(BetaAnalyticsDataStubSettings.java:164) ~[google-analytics-data-0.32.0.jar:0.32.0]
    at com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient.<init>(BetaAnalyticsDataClient.java:172) ~[google-analytics-data-0.32.0.jar:0.32.0]
    at com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(BetaAnalyticsDataClient.java:154) ~[google-analytics-data-0.32.0.jar:0.32.0]
    at com.verishare.wpanalyticshelper.controller.UsercountSevenDaysController.usercountSevenDays(UsercountSevenDaysController.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I've searched and I can find no reference to a class

com.google.auth.oauth2.Gdc**h**Credentials

existing anywhere, only

com.google.auth.oauth2.Gd**c**Credentials

e. g. with a missing "h"?

What gives - how can I create a GA4 BetaAnalyticsDataClient instance by directly referencing a client_secrets.json file from the classpath, NOT using the environment variable as the official GA4 example linked above illustrates?

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.verishare</groupId>
    <artifactId>WPAnalyticsHelper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    
    <!--Spring-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <!--Log4J-->    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--Google APIs Java client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-xml</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-analyticsreporting</artifactId>
            <version>v4-rev20190318-1.28.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-analytics</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev134-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.analytics</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-analytics-data</artifactId>
            <version>0.32.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev58-1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.verishare.wpanalyticshelper.Application</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/</link>
                        <link>https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/${project.http.version}/</link>
                    </links>
                    <doctitle>${project.name} ${project.version}</doctitle>
                    <windowtitle>${project.artifactId} ${project.version}</windowtitle>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Automatic-Module-Name>google.api.client.java6</Automatic-Module-Name>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-DocURL>https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/${project.version}/index.html</Bundle-DocURL>
                        <Bundle-Description>Java 6 extensions to the Google APIs Client Library for Java</Bundle-Description>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.google.api.client.java6</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>source-jar</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>-->
            <!--Set minimum requirement to Java 7-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <signature>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                        <artifactId>java17</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </signature>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                             
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Imports used:

```
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataSettings;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.classfile.Utility;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.verishare.log4J2.utils.LogEntryRefNumGen;
import com.verishare.wpanalyticshelper.model.UsercountSevenDaysModel;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Objects;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this was to ensure that the referenced Maven artifacts were pointing to the correct versions of the required GA4 dependencies.

With the same Java code as above using these imports

```
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataSettings;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.DateRange;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.Dimension;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.Metric;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.RunReportRequest;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.RunReportResponse;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
```

with this pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.verishare</groupId>
    <artifactId>WPAnalyticsHelper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    
    <!--Spring-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <!--Log4J-->    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--Google APIs Java client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-xml</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-analyticsreporting</artifactId>
            <version>v4-rev20190318-1.28.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-analytics</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev134-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.analytics</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-analytics-data</artifactId>
            <version>0.33.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev58-1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.verishare.wpanalyticshelper.Application</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/</link>
                        <link>https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/${project.http.version}/</link>
                    </links>
                    <doctitle>${project.name} ${project.version}</doctitle>
                    <windowtitle>${project.artifactId} ${project.version}</windowtitle>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Automatic-Module-Name>google.api.client.java6</Automatic-Module-Name>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-DocURL>https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/${project.version}/index.html</Bundle-DocURL>
                        <Bundle-Description>Java 6 extensions to the Google APIs Client Library for Java</Bundle-Description>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.google.api.client.java6</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>source-jar</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>-->
            <!--Set minimum requirement to Java 7-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <signature>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                        <artifactId>java17</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </signature>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                             
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

solved my issue and the code now compiles and runs and no longer crashes with the above runtime exception.